# How to check the integrity of a bunch of files?

Tags: php, integer, integrity

I need a reasonable way to use PHP to check the integrity of a large number of files that is present below a directory on a specific server (*large number* here means 6000 and more).

Basically, I want to know if they have been altered.  The solution I've come up with is to compute a hash value of all the files as follows:

```
$accnum = 1;
$modulo = PHP_INT_MAX >> 5;
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $crc32 = crc32(md5_file($file));
  $accnum = ($accnum % $modulo) * 31 + $crc32;
}
$hash = md5($accnum);
```

I then record the hash somewhere an intruder can't reach it.

Then, to check for tampering, I recompute the hash and compare it to the recorded value.  If it is different, I know that at least one of files have been altered.

Questions:
- Is this a reasonable way to do this?
- If not, how do I monitor the integrity of a large number of files?

Comment: To speed things up, you might also want to store the last modified date of the file and only compare the hash if the date has changed. This should speed up the application as date checking should be less time consuming than checking the hash. I don't know if this is the best solution for  your case, but it is something to consider.

Comment: another possibility is to 'watch' the directory for 'filesystem' events. Something like [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) may be useful?

Comment: Your 'hash' method will work fine. Also keep 'offline backups' of your website of your own as well as 'backups' provided by the 'hosting provider'.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use [Git](https://git-scm.com/) for that? Keep a remote repository where your "intruder" cannot reach and watch for local changes or compare your code with the remote repo.

Comment: I use Git to monitor local changes for this in some other contexts. In this case, I only want to monitor a subset of the files and maintaining `.gitignore` would be a nightmare. (I am not the downvoter tho'.)

Comment: No prob. I believe that git is a great way of keeping track of changes and at the same time checking integrity because everything in git is check-summed using a SHA-1 hash and the implementation is really fast. You can choose to whitelist files in .gitignore, too.